# how to show sup Total in WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

any one Kindly help me solve this problem and i have no idea about this

only i have wpf xaml code without class file.... i don't know how to create a class file for this xaml code and i took this xaml code from this Link [how to handle group subtotal and e.g. target rows in WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652203/how-to-handle-group-subtotal-and-e-g-target-rows-in-wpf-datagrid?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
        <my:ExtendedDataGrid.FooterDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Rows Count:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Foreground="DarkGreen"  
                               Text="{Binding ElementName=dgReport, Path=Items.Count}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </my:ExtendedDataGrid.FooterDataTemplate>

        <my:ExtendedDataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsExpanded="True"
                                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DataGrid Name="HeaderGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., 
                                            Converter={StaticResource SumConverter}}"
                                                    Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded" HeadersVisibility="Row"
                                                    Margin="25 0 0 0" PreviewMouseDown="HeaderGrid_PreviewMouseDown">
                                            <DataGrid.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, 
                                                            Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGrid.Style>
                                        </DataGrid>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        <DataGrid Name="FooterGrid" 
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=HeaderGrid, Path=ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                        Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded" HeadersVisibility="Row" IsReadOnly="False"
                                                        Margin="0" RowHeight="25" CanUserAddRows="False">
                                            <DataGrid.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                                     Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGrid.Style>
                                        </DataGrid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
        </my:ExtendedDataGrid.GroupStyle>

    </my:ExtendedDataGrid>
```

thanking you