# WPF Datagrid Grouping and totals

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, footer, summary

I have a **WPF Datagrid** in a **.net 4.6 MVVM project**.

The datagrid is binded to a ListCollectionView.  It allows me to sort/filter quickly.
The grid is editable in some cells.
Actually, the grid works great, it is quick, it shows tons of data.  There is like 25 columns [sales per month, inventory per month, turn over, etc..].
It works, its good.

Here is my actual grid appearance (in excel, but it is the same) : 
[image]

And here is what we try to achieve:
[image]

So here what we want  :

1. A summary row at the bottom of the grid (like a frozen row, always visible.
2. The ability to create "virtual row" that are parent of child.
3. The columns between parent and childs are the SAME :  The column width must always match. I dont want to create binded width [with of a column is equal to width of the other column of the other grid].

Some other thing : I'd really like not to pollute my base data (in the ListCollectionView) with "summary row". It will be ugly, I it is a display concern. If I pollute my date, i will have to create all sort of protection and if then else...

i've search the net waaaay to long (Xceed, Component1, Xtended Toolkit, Telerik...).  I found, in my journey, lots of great article and comparison :
 - Someone testing them : http://developers-club.com/posts/167751/ 
 - this one seems half-way good:   http://thibaud60.blogspot.ca/2008/10/wpftoolkit-datagrid-with-footer-and.html
but NO ONE does what I wants [to be honest, i did not downloaded and tried every of them].

So please, tell me that there is something out there?

thanks

Comment: Yes your are right, it is 90% of what I want.  i never found that one on SO. i'll mark as duplicate and just make a ref from there to this question (maybe the images will help somebody).  
Anyway, i have a feeling that there is NO answer to that question.  
My fear is that WPF is....cryogenized (not dead but..)...:\ thanks

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this question is not viewed, nor answered (even the "duplicate" is not answered).  I am working with some relics?? Is it because WPF/DAtagrid is a wrong choice that I cannot find any decent answers???  How does peoples develops on Windows thick client??